# Kivy app crashing with no non-static method openAPKExpansionInputStream

Tags: java, android, python, java-native-interface, kivy

I've been racking my brain over this for the past week or so and really need some help. My apk builds fine, and running main.py works perfectly on linux, however, when running the apk on my galaxy s6, it crashes shortly after opening. I've tried updating buildozer, kivy, ensured all dependencies have been met and are included in the spec file (below). As well as trying a myriad of other solutions such as changing api, updating all build tools etc.

Anyone have any ideas? Here is a link to the logcat,

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8d571dc4fdcd128087f90902ee702d34

and it indicates a fatal signal 6 error, as well as a JNI error (copied below) but I'm not sure what exactly they relate to in this case. I'm not well versed in programming by any means, so some support would be greatly appreciated.

***Logcat errors***

> 06-19 16:05:20.381 22274 22301 F art     :
>   art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410] JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: JNI
>   CallStaticVoidMethod called with pending exception
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: no non-static method
>   "Lorg/kivy/android/PythonActivity;.openAPKExpansionInputStream(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/io/InputStream;"

AND

> 06-19 16:05:20.521  3113  3113 F DEBUG   : signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6
>   (SI_TKILL), fault addr -------- 06-19 16:05:20.541  3113  3113 F DEBUG
>   : Abort message: 'art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410] JNI DETECTED ERROR
>   IN APPLICATION: JNI CallStaticVoidMethod called with pending exception
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: no non-static method
>   "Lorg/kivy/android/PythonActivity;.openAPKExpansionInputStream(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/io/InputStream;"'

```
#Buildozer spec file

[app]

# (str) Title of your application
title = Shooty shapes

# (str) Package name
package.name = ShootyShapes

# (str) Package domain (needed for android/ios packaging)
package.domain = org.test

# (str) Source code where the main.py live
source.dir = .

# (list) Source files to include (let empty to include all the files)
source.include_exts = py,png,jpg,kv,atlas,ttf,txt,mp3

# (list) List of inclusions using pattern matching
#source.include_patterns = assets/*,images/*.png

# (list) Source files to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_exts = spec

# (list) List of directory to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
source.exclude_dirs = tests, bin, images, buildddd, python-for-android

# (list) List of exclusions using pattern matching
#source.exclude_patterns = license,images/*/*.jpg

# (str) Application versioning (method 1)
version = 0.1

# (str) Application versioning (method 2)
# version.regex = __version__ = ['"](.*)['"]
# version.filename = %(source.dir)s/main.py

# (list) Application requirements
# comma seperated e.g. requirements = sqlite3,kivy
requirements = kivy==master,plyer,android,hostpython2

# (str) Custom source folders for requirements
# Sets custom source for any requirements with recipes
# requirements.source.kivy = ../../kivy

# (list) Garden requirements
#garden_requirements =

# (str) Presplash of the application
#presplash.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/presplash.png

# (str) Icon of the application
#icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/icon.png

# (str) Supported orientation (one of landscape, portrait or all)
orientation = landscape

# (list) List of service to declare
#services = NAME:ENTRYPOINT_TO_PY,NAME2:ENTRYPOINT2_TO_PY

#
# OSX Specific
#

#
# author = © Copyright Info

#
# Android specific
#

# (bool) Indicate if the application should be fullscreen or not
fullscreen = 1

# (list) Permissions
android.permissions = INTERNET,VIBRATE

# (int) Android API to use
android.api = 16

# (int) Minimum API required
#android.minapi = 9

# (int) Android SDK version to use
#android.sdk = 20

# (str) Android NDK version to use
#android.ndk = 9c

# (bool) Use --private data storage (True) or --dir public storage (False)
#android.private_storage = True

# (str) Android NDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.ndk_path =

# (str) Android SDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.sdk_path =

# (str) ANT directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.ant_path =

# (str) python-for-android git clone directory (if empty, it will be automatically cloned from github)
android.p4a_dir = .

# (list) python-for-android whitelist
#android.p4a_whitelist =

# (bool) If True, then skip trying to update the Android sdk
# This can be useful to avoid excess Internet downloads or save time
# when an update is due and you just want to test/build your package
# android.skip_update = False

# (str) Bootstrap to use for android builds (android_new only)
# android.bootstrap = sdl2

# (str) Android entry point, default is ok for Kivy-based app
#android.entrypoint = org.renpy.android.PythonActivity

# (list) List of Java .jar files to add to the libs so that pyjnius can access
# their classes. Don't add jars that you do not need, since extra jars can slow
# down the build process. Allows wildcards matching, for example:
# OUYA-ODK/libs/*.jar
#android.add_jars = foo.jar,bar.jar,path/to/more/*.jar

# (list) List of Java files to add to the android project (can be java or a
# directory containing the files)
#android.add_src =

# (str) python-for-android branch to use, if not master, useful to try
# not yet merged features.
#android.branch = master

# (str) OUYA Console category. Should be one of GAME or APP
# If you leave this blank, OUYA support will not be enabled
#android.ouya.category = GAME

# (str) Filename of OUYA Console icon. It must be a 732x412 png image.
#android.ouya.icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/ouya_icon.png

# (str) XML file to include as an intent filters in <activity> tag
#android.manifest.intent_filters =

# (list) Android additionnal libraries to copy into libs/armeabi
#android.add_libs_armeabi = libs/android/*.so
#android.add_libs_armeabi_v7a = libs/android-v7/*.so
#android.add_libs_x86 = libs/android-x86/*.so
#android.add_libs_mips = libs/android-mips/*.so

# (bool) Indicate whether the screen should stay on
# Don't forget to add the WAKE_LOCK permission if you set this to True
#android.wakelock = False

# (list) Android application meta-data to set (key=value format)
#android.meta_data =

# (list) Android library project to add (will be added in the
# project.properties automatically.)
#android.library_references =

# (str) Android logcat filters to use
#android.logcat_filters = *:S python:D

# (bool) Copy library instead of making a libpymodules.so
#android.copy_libs = 1

#
# iOS specific
#

# (str) Path to a custom kivy-ios folder
#ios.kivy_ios_dir = ../kivy-ios

# (str) Name of the certificate to use for signing the debug version
# Get a list of available identities: buildozer ios list_identities
#ios.codesign.debug = "iPhone Developer: <lastname> <firstname> (<hexstring>)"

# (str) Name of the certificate to use for signing the release version
#ios.codesign.release = %(ios.codesign.debug)s


[buildozer]

# (int) Log level (0 = error only, 1 = info, 2 = debug (with command output))
log_level = 2

# (int) Display warning if buildozer is run as root (0 = False, 1 = True)
warn_on_root = 1

# (str) Path to build artifact storage, absolute or relative to spec file
# build_dir = ./.buildozer

# (str) Path to build output (i.e. .apk, .ipa) storage
# bin_dir = ./bin

#    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    List as sections
#
#    You can define all the "list" as [section:key].
#    Each line will be considered as a option to the list.
#    Let's take [app] / source.exclude_patterns.
#    Instead of doing:
#
#[app]
#source.exclude_patterns = license,data/audio/*.wav,data/images/original/*
#
#    This can be translated into:
#
#[app:source.exclude_patterns]
#license
#data/audio/*.wav
#data/images/original/*
#


#    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    Profiles
#
#    You can extend section / key with a profile
#    For example, you want to deploy a demo version of your application without
#    HD content. You could first change the title to add "(demo)" in the name
#    and extend the excluded directories to remove the HD content.
#
#[app@demo]
#title = My Application (demo)
#
#[app:source.exclude_patterns@demo]
#images/hd/*
#
#    Then, invoke the command line with the "demo" profile:
#
#buildozer --profile demo android debug
```

Any help would be really useful

Comment: Very strange - this looks like a problem with SDL2's internal stuff, but I've never seen such a problem before (or seen anyone else report the same thing). Just to check, does this happen even with a simple test app?

Comment: I've tried with a simple hello world app and i get the same crash shortly into running the app. However the error is different on the logcat. @inclement

Comment: Pressed enter by mistake sorry. I've tried with a simple hello world app and i get the same crash shortly into running the app. However the error is different on the logcat at line 95 https://gist.github.com/anonymous/cd1d2a2ad91311c48b83d2ff575e9185. Also i had trouble compiling hello world in a seperate folder, which is strange? Got this error https://gist.github.com/anonymous/69d9e5e20438990d1c8c0004af64f946 @inclement

Answer (score 0):

I hit this error as well and had a torrid time tracking it down. It came from Window.set_icon("path/to/icon.png") method.

```
from kivy.core.window import Window
Window.set_icon("graphics/icon.png")
```

Once I commented this out, the error disappeared. It gave no issues using the previous android toolchain with buildozer (android_old), but occurrs when we switched to the new "android" target. It's an old post, but just putting it out there in case it helps...:-)